# Set Path Variable Permanently Using ShellExecuteEx

Tags: c, windows, path, shellexecuteex

I come up with this code. It will execute correctly and return true. but it doesn't change Path variable's  value. When I type like this --> setx Path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\"
in cmd, it works and change the Path value

here is the code

```
// Prepare shellExecutInfo
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShRun = {0};
ShRun.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShRun.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShRun.hwnd = NULL;
ShRun.lpVerb =NULL;
ShRun.lpFile = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\setx.exe";
ShRun.lpParameters = "Path \"\"\"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02\\bin\\\"\"\"";
ShRun.lpDirectory =NULL;
ShRun.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
ShRun.hInstApp = NULL;

// Execute the file with the parameters
if(ShellExecuteEx(&ShRun))
    printf("done");
else
    printf("no");
```

what will be the problem here??

Comment: Works fine here. Can you describe how you are diagnosing failure.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I execute this and run but it didn't add this Path to Path Enviroment variable

Comment: Please be precise. Describe the exact steps you took to verify that.

Comment: I go to Start-->Contorl Panal --> Advance System Setting --> Enviroment Variable   then look into "User Variable" Section and "System Variable" Section. but I didn't saw that there is any change happend.

Comment: Also, your code leaks the process handle. You set `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS` but then do nothing with the handle.

Comment: The quoting looks funny. Should be `ShRun.lpParameters = "Path \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02\\bin\\\"";`

Comment: change it as you say, but it also would not work ??

Comment: Thank you @DavidHeffernan for helping me. I'm able to fix that issue using ShellExecute. Thanks Again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quoting on the arguments is wrong. You have too many quotes. You need to write

```
ShRun.lpParameters = "Path \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02\\bin\\\"";
```

To see that your version will fail I did the following experiment at the console:

```
C:\Users\heff>setx path """C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\"""
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
```

I also note that you are using `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`. Normally you do that so that you can then wait on the process handle that is returned. You don't appear to be doing that. What's more, you don't appear to be closing the process handle which is your responsibility when you use `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`.

Comment: I fixed the quoting but result is same

Comment: I get a security dialog when I compile the code into a simple `int main()` program using g++. When I compile with the MS compiler or call `ShellExecute` from a Delphi app, it's all good. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: You might want to mention the "destroyed in 10 seconds" failure mode of changing the PATH environment variable like that. Lots of extremely hard to diagnose problems when the Windows directories are no longer on the PATH. You'd better check your own machine too if you actually did this ;)  The damage isn't immediately obvious, it requires a log-out to make the new setting effective.

Comment: @Hans It just modifies the user variable which is then merged with the system variable. And I was super careful. Rapid Environment Editor was used.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm using gcc compiler in MinGW32

Comment: @HansPassant I Restart machine but it not effected

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant for helping me. I'm able to fix that issue using ShellExecute. Thanks Again

Comment: @Aspen What do you mean? Hans didn't talk about `ShellExecute`. What issue did you fix?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I mean I fix my issue using ShellExecute.Issue is what my early code didn't set the path correctly. now it sets the path correctly.